# Differentiation in one real variable

Tags: analysis

If $p(x)$ is a polynomial , prove that there  is a root  of $p'(x)+kp(x)=0$ for some real $k$, between any two real roots of $p(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

I did not downvote, but a little effort on your behalf would be appreciated.
Here is a way (I stress "a" way) how to set it up.
Let there be two real roots $x=a$ and $x=b$ with $a<b$ for which $p(x)=0$, as given. This implies $k(a)=k(b)=0$. Let there be an $x=c$ such that $a<c<b$. Since $p(x)$ is a polynomial and thus continuous, can you apply Rolle's Theorem here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct consequence of Rolle's Theorem: simply let $k=0$ and the equation becomes $p'(x)=0$.

Comment: By Rolle's theorem we get P'(c)=0 for a<c<b.but P'(c) +kP(c) =0 how this is where i am stucked

Comment: We just have to find some k that satisfies that equation. Setting k equal to 0 removes your P(c) term.